# Is it possible to have a conditional in a launch file using DeclareLaunchArgument

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a setup of hierarchical launch files, and I would like to use a launch argument to determine whether or not certain launch actions in them run. I already have a launch argument working via DeclareLaunchArgument that determines the namespace  the node launches in, and I was hoping I could use another launch argument to run a simple if statement before adding an action to my launch description, *launch_me*.

The code below shows my attempt to implement this, but it does not work.

```
def generate_launch_description():
bridge_topics = join(get_package_share_directory('piracer'),
                     'config', 'ackermann_bridge_topics.yaml')
launch_directory = get_package_share_directory('piracer')

launch_me = LaunchDescription()

car_name_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('car_name', default_value='car1',
                                    description='Sets the namespace for this car.')

hardware_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('should_launch_hardware', default_value='true',
                                    description='Determines if hardware_nodes.launch is called.')

hardware_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([launch_directory, '/hardware_nodes.launch.py']),
    launch_arguments={'car_name': LaunchConfiguration('car_name')}.items()
)
ackermann_node = Node(
    package='piracer',
    namespace=[LaunchConfiguration('car_name')],
    executable='ackermann_controller',
    name='ackermann_controller',
    parameters=[bridge_topics]
)
launch_me.add_action(car_name_arg)
launch_me.add_action(hardware_arg)
if LaunchConfiguration('should_launch_hardware') == 'true':
    launch_me.add_action(hardware_launch)
launch_me.add_action(ackermann_node)

return launch_me
```

Is it possible to use a launch argument as a conditional in a launch file?

---

**EDIT: Solved thanks to djchopp!** To properly add the conditional, I had to do four things:

1. Add an import statement for `IfCondition`
2. Add a launch configuration, which I called `should_launch_hardware`.
3. Add the condition to the `hardware_launch` launch action.
4. Remove the useless if-statement around adding the `hardware_launch` action to `launch_me`. It will be added every time, but using the condition `should_launch_hardware`, ROS will decide if it actually gets executed or not.

A summary of the additions I made to the code are shown below:

```
from launch.conditions import IfCondition #1
....
should_launch_hardware = LaunchConfiguration('should_launch_hardware') #2
....
hardware_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([launch_directory, '/hardware_nodes.launch.py']),
        launch_arguments={'car_name': LaunchConfiguration('car_name')}.items(),
        condition=IfCondition(should_launch_hardware)   #3
    )
```

The entire new launch file looks like this:

```
# Standard library imports
from os.path import join

# Third-party imports
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.conditions import IfCondition #1
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration


def generate_launch_description():
    bridge_topics = join(get_package_share_directory('piracer'),
                         'config', 'ackermann_bridge_topics.yaml')
    launch_directory = get_package_share_directory('piracer')

    should_launch_hardware = LaunchConfiguration('should_launch_hardware')  #2

    launch_me = LaunchDescription()

    car_name_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('car_name', default_value='car1',
                                         description='Sets the namespace for this car.')

    hardware_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('should_launch_hardware', default_value='true',
                                         description='Determines if hardware_nodes.launch is called.')

    hardware_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([launch_directory, '/hardware_nodes.launch.py']),
        launch_arguments={'car_name': LaunchConfiguration('car_name')}.items(),
        condition=IfCondition(should_launch_hardware) #3
    )
    ackermann_node = Node(
        package='piracer',
        namespace=[LaunchConfiguration('car_name')],
        executable='ackermann_controller',
        name='ackermann_controller',
        parameters=[bridge_topics]
    )
    launch_me.add_action(car_name_arg)
    launch_me.add_action(hardware_arg)
    launch_me.add_action(hardware_launch) #4
    launch_me.add_action(ackermann_node)

    return launch_me
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382167/is-it-possible-to-have-a-conditional-in-a-launch-file-using-declarelaunchargument/) by [marshallpt](https://answers.ros.org/users/77474/marshallpt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-07-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Long answer short, yes it supports conditionals but you have to use the dedicated conditional functionality and not plain python. See [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/382000/ros2-makes-launch-files-crazy-too-soon-to-be-migrating/?answer=382141#post-id-382141) I recently wrote that describes how to do what you are asking.

You can see the currently supported conditions in the [source code](https://github.com/ros2/launch/tree/master/launch/launch/conditions)

At time of writing you can use: `IfCondition`, `UnlessCondition`, `LaunchConfigurationEquals`, `LaunchConfigurationNotEquals`

The `IfCondition` and `UnlessCondition` follow these rules:

```
A string will be considered True if it matches 'true' or '1'.
A string will be considered False if it matches 'false' or '0'.
Any other string content (including empty string) will result in an error.
```

You can use `LaunchConfigurationEquals`, `LaunchConfigurationNotEquals` to cover cases where the launch configuration does not follow the rules above.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [djchopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/74140/djchopp/) with karma: 328 on 2021-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marshallpt](https://answers.ros.org/users/77474/marshallpt/) on 2021-07-12**:
This was exactly what I needed! Thank you!

I fully agree with your assessment that ROS2 launch is good, just lacking in documentation. I had no idea the `launch.conditions` library existed!

**Comment by [marshallpt](https://answers.ros.org/users/77474/marshallpt/) on 2021-07-27**:
For anyone looking for how to use `LaunchConfigurationEquals` or `LaunchConfigurationNotEquals`, I used [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/360264/ifconditionpythonexpression-am-i-doing-it-right/?answer=360275#post-id-360275) and read the docstring in [this](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/launch/conditions/launch_configuration_equals.py) bit of the source code. The folder containing that file has all 4 currently available conditions.